# NSM Addon Updater not working with P&T modules

Tags: pixelandtonic

Congratulations to P&T on all the changes lately, brilliant work!

I've used noticed after the P&T website was changed and all the modules updates are handled by http://devot-ee.com/ the NSM Addon Updater they used to support is not working, I can only assume they need to change the config file in the module.

Is it still possible to use NSM add-on updater with P&T add-ons?

Answer (score 1):

devot:ee doesn’t support NSM Addon Updater. I’ve suggested it to Ryan, and we’ve left the URLs in our latest round of updates, so if they ever add it, we can add some 301 redirects on pixelandtonic.com.

Something tells me it won't ever happen though. Most people have moved on to [devot:ee Monitor](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/devotee-monitor) at this point, for good reason.

Answer (score 0):

It might only be updated through the [devot-ee Monitor](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/devotee-monitor) add-on now.